# How to configure AWS Cloudwatch Event Rule for checking IAM roles for the service account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to configure a Cloudwatch Event Rule for whenever someone assumes an IAM role for the service account:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.sts"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "sts.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
    ]
  }
}
```

For the simple AssumeRole it works OK but for this type (AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity) of the role it doesn't show any event.
Does anyone configure Cloudwatch Event Rules for checking IAM roles for the service account?
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly do you mean with “IAM role for the service account”? Who or what is assuming the respective roles and through which mechanism?

Comment: @DennisTraub It allows applying roles for pods (connected with service accounts) in AWS EKS instead of applying wide roles for the worker nodes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: Maybe it also goes under the AssumeRole event but gets a different set of parameters? If you change the event to AssumeRole do you see the web federation events?

Comment: Yes @TamásSallai I'm able to see events from AssumeRole, but in these events, there is only information about AssumeRole. I've tried many others set of parameters but currently unlucky

Comment: I found this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-user-identity.html . Do you see any webIdFederationData or something in the sessionIssuer in the event?

Comment: Yes @TamásSallai in the cloudtrail I'm seeing a lot of events with event name AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity. It shows me the correct IRSA OIDC provider

"userIdentity": {
        "type": "WebIdentityUser",
        "principalId": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:sts.amazonaws.com:system:serviceaccount:namespace:sa",
        "userName": "system:serviceaccount:namespace:sa",
        "identityProvider": "arn:aws:iam:xxxxx::oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    },